# Datagram Socket "must be caught or declared to be thrown"

Tags: java

The following code is producing an error

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
```

The java.net.* is included at the top

The error is `unreported exception java.net.SocketException; must be caught or d
eclared to be thrown`

It's in a method run() in a class that uses a thread.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you catch it in a try/catch block and log it, or change your Runnable to be a Callable<Void> which can throw an excaption.

BTW: I would use an ExecutorService rather than a plain Thread as it allows you to recycle your Threads and manage them easier.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is as clear as it can possibly be.  Either put in a `catch` block:

```
try {
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    // ...
}
catch (SocketException ex)
{
     // ...
}
```

Or declare that the method you're creating the socket in can possibly throw a `SocketException`:

```
void foo() throws SocketException
{
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    // ...
}
```

Java has checked exceptions, meaning that the compiler watches for these things for you.  I can't say it's a good part of the language, but it's a mandatory part.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are not catching the possible SocketException that might occur

```
try {
   DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```